# Custom indentation rules

Tags: netbeans, indentation, laravel-blade

I develop website on Netbeans IDE.
Currently I'm working with Laravel Framework, and I use the **Blade template engine** which allow to create loop or conditional statement in HTML views without having to jump from HTML to PHP, then to HTML again, ...

However each of Blade's statement aren't recognize as HTML or PHP object, and so Netbeans doesn't make any indentation of them:

```
@if($isConnected)
<div id="aDiv">...
@else
<div>...
```

I'd prefer it looks like:

```
@if($isConnected)
    <div id="aDiv">...
@else
    <div>...
```

**Is there a way to teach new indentation rules to Netbeans?**